# Android, Espresso: Show/Hide view depends of item content

Tags: android-espresso

I has listView of items (person). When I click of any item in list then open personDetails in separate Activity. Object personDetails has property **age**.

I need to test (by Espresso) the next:

If property personDetails.**age** is not NULL then button **Next** is displayed. Else button **Next** is not displayed.

Comment: 1. Show person details.
2. Check if property "age" not null
3. If not null then show button Next
4. Else not show button Next

Answer (score 0):

Implement the next test scenario:

1. Add new person with age not Null.
2. Find this new item (scroll to it) in your listView.
3. Click on it.
4. Check that button Next is displaying.
5. Change age to Null.
6. Check that button Next is not displaying.
7. Remove new person from database after test completed.